# iPhone and Twitter API OAuth Consumer Keys and Secrets

Tags: iphone, uitableview, twitter, tableview, mgtwitterengine

I have a issue while loading my data from Twitter. The method I posted below works for about 5-10 minutes then it freezes up my consumer keys....

I know it is the keys because I have the app already installed on the device working then I will make changes and run on the simulator and it affects the device as well. This last for about 30 minutes then the keys seem to refresh themselves and work without any changes to the actual code. Sometimes I will just go in Twitter Dev were my application is and reset the keys and replace the keys in my code and that works for about 10 minutes then the same thing happens!

Here is the code I am using to call out to twitter OAuth and receive the objects for my `UITableView`.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(_engine) return;

    _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];
    _engine.consumerKey = @"key";
    _engine.consumerSecret = @"key";

    UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine: _engine delegate: self];

    if (controller) 
        [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
    else
    {
        userAvatar.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1361674958/Wintboard_200px.png" ]]];

        tweets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        authors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        avatarsURL =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        friendsCount = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        followerCount = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        retweetCount = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        //retweetCount = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [self updateStream:nil];
        [progressView.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

#pragma mark IBActions 

-(IBAction)updateStream:(id)sender
{
    // [_engine sendUpdate:[textfield text]];
    [_engine getFollowedTimelineSinceID:0 startingAtPage:0 count:100];

    //[_twitter getFollowedTimelineSinceID:0 startingAtPage:0 count:0];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"unlock" ofType:@"caf"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
}

-(IBAction)tweet:(id)sender
{   
    [_engine sendUpdate:[textfield text]];
    [self updateStream:nil];
    if (textfield isFirstResponder])
    {
        textfield.text = @"";
        [textfield resignFirstResponder];
    }
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField*)textfield
{
    return  YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // the user pressed the "Done" button, so dismiss the keyboard
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

// Return YES for supported orientations

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource Methods 

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section    
{    
    // [_engine sendUpdate:[textfield text]];
    [_engine getFollowedTimelineSinceID:0 startingAtPage:0 count:100];

    int count = [tweets count];
    int count2 = [authors count];
    int count3 = [avatarsURL count];

    //Return just enough cells to fill the screen during loading ....
    if (count == 0)
        count = MyCustomRowCount;

    return count = 100;
    return count2 = 100;
    return count3 = 100;

    // return  count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    { 
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
    }

/*
    //Here it adds a nice shadow to the table view but will crash on rotation and send a wird dump 
    tableView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    tableView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
    tableView.layer.shadowRadius = 8.0f;
    tableView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;     
*/

    [cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:1];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[(Tweet*)[authors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] author]];  

    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[(Tweet*)[tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] tweet]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setNumberOfLines:10];
    [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [cell.textLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [cell.textLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.5, 0.5)];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    //[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[(Tweet*)[retweetCount objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] reTweetCount]];
    [cell.textLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [cell.contentView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

    // Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image with SDWebImageManager
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[(Tweet*)[avatarsURL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]avatarURL]]
    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.png"]];

    //add gradient to cell 
    UIImage *gradient = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gradientcell2.png"];
    UIImageView *cellimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:gradient];
    cellimage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    cell.backgroundView = cellimage;

    [cellimage release];      

    UIImage *selectedGradient = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedcell.png"];
    UIImageView *selectedCell = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:selectedGradient];
    selectedCell.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedCell;    

    [tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Did you find solution for this ??? as i can see even my keys stop working after a period of time

Answer (score 1):

Yes Sorry I should have came back and answered this!

First make sure your requests are not going over Twitters API request Limit, I was simply while reloading my table view.

After Fixing that mistake I the proceeded to reset my keys wrote a request to Twitter API to use xAuth "it only takes a few days to be accepted" then I have not had any issues since.

I did not use my keys until I received the letter from Twitter saying I was accepted and I have not had any issues since.

I hope this helps because I know how frustrating that can become !

Good Luck!